# How do you properly unmarshall an SOAP string with XML namespaces?

Tags: go

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to correctly and safely unmarshall a SOAP response with the following shape:

```xml
<xml>
    <soap-env:Envelope
        xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap-env:Header></soap-env:Header>
        <soap-env:Body>
            <n0:ZcustomerMasterInfoResponse
                xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
                <EOutput>
                   ...Additional tags
                </EOutput>
            <n0:ZcustomerMasterInfoResponse/>
        </soap-env:Body />
      </soap:Envelop />
</xml>
```

This would be trivial with basic tags but there's quite a few namespaces such as soap-env, n0 etc. that are making it more complex to parse.